# Teamviewer and remote logins

Tags: passwords, teamviewer

Not sure if this has been asked before (a cursory search doesn't show anything), so I figure here is a sensible place to ask.

Say I am remotely controlling my desktop at home via Teamviewer. Now while I am connected, say I want to log in to something - e.g. switch user accounts. Now clearly that means typing my password at this end, and the key strokes being transmitted via teamviewer to the other end.

Is this actually secure? For example is there any way someone could log the keystrokes being sent and thus easily get the password.

I've been doing it for many months now, and its just dawned on me that maybe it is not that sensible. Not sure.

---

I haven't got any reason to think anyone has been spying on the connection (e.g. no evidence of passwords being compromised), but I'm just having one of those, what-if though moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teamviewer indicates they secure their connections client to client.

If implemented properly this should mean no one can intercept the data you send over the network in plain text, i.e. find you password and username, because the connection is encrypted.

In other words, in the case you describe (you connecting to your home computer) it should be secure, assuming you don't have any malware/keylogger running on your pc (but again: that has nothing to do with Teamviewer).

The same may not be true if you connect via Teamviewer to a client his computer. Not because the connection is not secure, but because the PC you are connecting to might have monitoring software enabled.

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/security.aspx

Comment: Good to know. I'm only connecting to PC which *theoretically* nobody but me has access too - I've blacklisted all connections via teamviewer except my laptop.

Comment: It should be noted that Teamviewer can be stealing everything you see and type.